# What's the -complete- list of kinds of automatic type conversions a C++ compiler will do for a function argument?

Tags: c++

Given a C++ function f(X x) where x is a variable of type X, and a variable y of type Y, what are all the automatic/implicit conversions the C++ compiler will perform on y so that the statement "f(y);" is legal code (no errors, no warnings)?

For example:

Pass Derived& to function taking Base& - ok
Pass Base& to function Derived& - not ok without a cast
Pass int to function taking long - ok, creates a temporary long
Pass int& to function taking long& - NOT ok, taking reference to temporary

Note how the built-in types have some quirks compared to classes:  a Derived can be passed to function taking a Base (although it gets sliced), and an int can be passed to function taking a long, but you cannot pass an int& to a function taking a long&!!

What's the complete list of cases that are always "ok" (don't need to use any cast to do it)?

What it's for:  I have a C++ script-binding library that lets you bind your C++ code and it will call C++ functions at runtime based on script expressions.  Since expressions are evaluated at runtime, all the legal combinations of source types and function argument types that might need to be used in an expression have to be anticipated ahead of time and precompiled in the library so that they'll be usable at runtime.  If I miss a legal combination, some reasonable expressions won't work in runtime expressions; if I accidently generate a combination that isn't legal C++, my library just won't compile.

Edit (narrowing the question):

Thanks, all of your answers are actually pretty helpful.  I knew the answer was complicated, but it sounds like I've only seen the tip of the iceberg.

Let me rephrase the question a little then to limit its scope then:
I will let the user specify a list of "BaseClasses" and a list of "UserDefinedConversions".  For Bases, I'll generate everything including reference and pointer conversions.  But what cases (const/reference/pointer) can I safely do from the UserDefined Conversions list?  (The user will give bare types, I will decorate with *, &, const, etc. in the template.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Note how the built-in types have some
>   quirks compared to classes: a Derived
>   can be passed to function taking a
>   Base (although it gets sliced), and an
>   int can be passed to function taking a
>   long, but you cannot pass an int& to a
>   function taking a long&!!

That's not a quirk of built-in vs. class types. It's a quirk of inheritance.

If you had classes A and B, and B had a conversion to A (either because A has a constructor taking B, or because B has a conversion operator to A), then they'd behave just like int and long in this respect - conversion can occur where a function takes a value, but not where it takes a non-const reference. In both cases the problem is that there is no object to which the necessary non-const reference can be taken: a long& can't refer to an int, and an A& can't refer to a B, and no non-const reference can refer to a temporary.

The reason the base/derived example doesn't encounter this problem because a non-const Base reference *can* refer to a Derived object. The fact that the types are user-defined is a necessary but not a sufficient condition for the reference to be legal. Convertible user-defined classes where there is no inheritance behave just like built-ins.

This comment is way too long for comments, so I've used an answer. It doesn't actually answer your question, though, other than to distinguish between:

- "Conversions" where a reference to a derived class is passed to a function taking a reference to a base class.
- Conversions where a user-defined or built-in conversion actually creates an object, such as from int to long.

Comment: All of the answers were acceptable, but this answer provided me with some important additional information (I wasn't sure before reading this whether user defined conversions acted like the int to long conversion).

Answer (score 6):

C++ Standard gives the answer to your question in **13.3.3.1  Implicit conversion sequences**, but it too large to post it here. I recommend you to read at least that part of C++ Standard.

Hope [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81656/where-do-i-find-the-current-x-standard#83763) link will help you.

Comment: I figured it was in a standards document, but I wasn't sure where to find it.  Thank you for the link.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately the answer to your question is hugely complex, occupying at least 9 pages in the ISO C++ standard (specifically: ~6 pages in "3 Standard Conversions" and ~3 pages in "13.3.3.1 Implicit Conversion Sequences").

**Brief summary:** A conversion that does not require a cast is called an "implicit conversion sequence".  C++ has "standard conversions", which are conversions between fundamental types (such as `char` being promoted to `int`) and things such as array-to-pointer decay; there can be several of these in a row, hence the term "sequences".  C++ also permits user-defined conversions, which are defined by conversion functions and converting constructors.  The important thing to note is that **an implicit conversion sequence can have *at most one* user-defined conversion**, with optionally a sequence of standard conversions on either side -- C++ will never "chain" more than one user-defined conversion together without a cast.

(If anyone would like to flesh this post out with the full details, please go ahead...  But for me, that would just be too exhausting, sorry :-/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I only marked the other one accepted because it happened to mention a detail important to what I'm doing.  Your answer was good too.